# Extracting strings from a NSArray of objects, based on a array of NSStrings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

OK, this is a bit obscure, but it's giving me a headache.

If you have an array of strings

```
{@"1", @"2", @"4"}
```

And you have a array of Recipe objects

```
{ {recipe_name:@"Lasagna", recipe_id:@"1"}
  {recipe_name:@"Burger", recipe_id:@"2"}
  {recipe_name:@"Pasta", recipe_id:@"3"}
  {recipe_name:@"Roast Chicken", recipe_id:@"4"}
  {recipe_name:@"Sauerkraut", recipe_id:@"5"}
}
```

How would I, using the first array, create an array like this:

```
{@"Lasagna", @"Burger", @"Roast Chicken"}
```

In ither words, it is taking the numbers in the first array and creating an array of recipe_names where the recipe_id matches the numbers...

Answer (score 12):

Use an `NSPredicate` to specify the type of objects you want, then use `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` to select precisely those objects:

```
NSArray *recipeArray = /* array of recipe objects keyed by "recipe_id" strings */;
NSArray *keyArray = /* array of string "recipe_id" keys */;
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipe_id IN %@", keyArray];
NSArray *results = [recipeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

`NSPredicate` uses its own mini-language to build a predicate from a format. The format grammar is documented in the ["Predicate Programming Guide."](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1)

If you are targeting iOS 4.0+, a more flexible alternative is to use `-[NSArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:]`:

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [recipeArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
        ^BOOL (id el, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
            NSString *recipeID = [(Recipe *)el recipe_id];
            return [keyArray containsObject:recipeID];
        }];
NSArray *results = [recipeArray objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Answer (score 5):

Your array of recipe objects is basically a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *recipeDict =
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[recipes valueForKey:@"recipe_name"]
                              forKeys:[recipes valueForKey:@"recipe_id"]];
```

And on a dictionary you can use the Key-Value Coding method:

```
NSArray *result = [[recipeDict dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:recipeIDs] allValues];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `Recipe` objects are key-value compliant (which they almost always are) you can use a predicate like so:

```
NSArray *recipes= // array of Recipe objects
NSArray *recipeIDs=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipe_id IN %@", recipeIDs];
NSArray *filterdRecipes=[recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
NSArray *recipeNames=[filterdRecipes valueForKey:@"recipe_name"];
```